# Вытащить все ссылки на картинки из текстового поля

Tags: javascript, ссылки, синтаксический-анализ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно вытащить все ссылки на картинки из строки средствами JS без повтора?

Вот пытался разобраться с exec и match, но получается с трудом.
Разбирал этим:

```
var pattern = /^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/i;

strEx = pattern.exec(curStr);
```

Потом с помощью push заношу в массив, но проблема в том, что в strEx всегда только первая картинка, а для строк вида:

```
http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png
http://i.imgur.com/ZOfyh6U.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/IxdBnsd.png
```

Оно и вовсе отказывается работать. Пытался добавлять g и m модификаторы в регулярку, но тогда вообще ничего не работает.

Comment: Более-менее разобрался самостоятельно. Разбираю все картинки в строке, в цикле проверяю, является ли каждая картинкой и заношу в массив. 

    var pattern = /([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/igm; 
    var strEx;
    var curStr = $(this).val();
    var img;  
    strEx = curStr.match(pattern); 
    for (var prop in strEx){
    if (comPrevImages.length < 9 && strEx !== null){
       img = new Image();
       img.src = strEx[prop];
       img.onload = function(){ 
       if (in_array(strEx[prop],comPrevImages) === false){
         comPrevImages.push(strEx[prop]);
       }
    }

Comment: Так вот если ссылка одна, то нет проблем. А если несколько, то заносится только последняя. Не проходит проверку на картинку, судя по всему, перезаписывается в img новое значение. Как этого избежать? Пытался добавлять задержки или для каждой итерации цикла создавать свой img, но всё равно перезаписывается, и из трёх url записывается в comPrevImages только последний.

Не знаю, как у вас отформатировать код в комментариях, поэтому такой текст, извините.

Answer (score 1):

Почитай, примерно подобное: http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/43536-izvlechenie-s-sajjta-ssylok-na-izobrazheniya.html
Ссылка на хороший сайт по регулярным выражениям: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Мне не нужно ничего менять. Мне нужно получить в массиве ссылки на картинки. Меня особенно "радует" javascript.ru отсутствием описания функций. То что они там приведены замечательно, а потом сиди гадай что она делает и какую использовать, а какую не использовать. Поэтому если уж хотите дать что почитать, то дайте ссылку на нормальный сайт по JS с использованием регулярных выражений. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как ты получишь ссылки в массиве, если исходная строка неправильная?
regex даст только последнюю ссылку - это его ...особенность.
Может, лучше так:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#find-file').click(function(){
    getimage(0, encodeURIComponent($('#focusedInput').val()));
  });
  function getimage(id, image_key) {
     $('#imgbook')['attr']('src', './progress.gif');
     $['getJSON']('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=' + image_key + '&rsz=2&imgsz=medium&callback=?', function (json) {
         $('#imgbook')['attr']('src', (json['responseData']['results'][id]['url']));
         $('#imgbook')['error'](function () {
             if(json['responseData']['results'][++id]) getimage(id, image_key); //проверка, чтоб небыло бесконечного цикла
         });
     });
  };
});

</script>
<input id="focusedInput" value="сиськи" >
<button type="submit" id="find-file">Поиск</button>

<img id="imgbook" width="200" src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/smilies/smile.gif">
```

Comment: Я уже показал, как я получу ссылки в массиве, в предыдущем своём комментарии в этой теме. Код работает. in_array - просто маленькая функция для проверки, есть ли ссылка уже в глобальном массиве comPrevImages, в который заносятся все ссылки (чтобы исключить повторы). 

Но, как уже сказал, тот код всегда разбирает только последнюю ссылку. 
Если я вставлю "Текст + ссылка1 + ссылка2 + текст + ссылка3", то в массив попадёт только последняя. Вот и вопрос - почему? 

img успевает перезаписываться, прежде чем сработает .onload? Но я пытался создавать каждый раз новую img переменную, не помогло.

Comment: Разбирается строка нормально. В strEx попадают все 3 ссылки, а вот потом то ли перезаписываются, то ли ещё что-то. Это не то чтобы критично именно разобрать все 3 ссылки, можно и так, ведь даже соцсети на это забили и вытягивают только 1 ссылку на картинку из кучи вставленных, но разобраться бы хотелось в вопросе.

Comment: >regex даст только последнюю ссылку это его ...особенность"

Неправда, .match мне даёт все 3 ссылки, которые указаны в посте (укажу 10, выдаст все 10). Если я сделаю `strEx = curStr.match(pattern);`, а потом в цикле `for (var prop in strEx){ console.log(strEx[prop]); }`, то получу столько ссылок на картинки, сколько было в тексте. Но вот куда потом пропадают все, кроме последней? (Весь код опять же в другой ветке, выше.)